# Azure Mobile Service client query not returning control back to Xamarin Form android client app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.ios, azure-mobile-services, xamarin.forms

I am using Azure Mobile Service with Xamarin Form Android application to mostly query data from the azure table storage.

The current problem what I am facing is the azure mobile service client is not returning the control back right after the mobile service client
API  call ( This has been the case only with the Portable class library and android app project, but the same call returns result in normal .net 
library as I have used test project to verify the API).

The source code I have used as follows:

**Azure Mobile Service code:**

```
public class VerticalFarmController : TableController<VerticalFarm>
    {
        protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
        {
           base.Initialize(controllerContext);
            MobileServiceContext context = new MobileServiceContext();
            string connectionString = "My_StorageConnectionString";
            DomainManager = new StorageDomainManager<VerticalFarm>(connectionString, "VerticalFarm", Request, Services);
        }

        public Task<IEnumerable<VerticalFarm>> GetAllVerticalFarm(ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
        {
            return base.QueryAsync(queryOptions);
        }
}
```

**Xamarin Form Android app code:**

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
    {
        private const string ApiUrl = "[Mobile service Url]";
        private const string AppKey = "[Application key]";


        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

            IMobileServiceClient mobileServiceClient = new MobileServiceClient(ApiUrl, AppKey);

            try
            {
                var table = mobileServiceClient.GetTable("verticalfarm");
                var result = table.ReadAsync("$top=10", null, wrapResult: true).Result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }

            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }
```

It neither returns result nor an exception right after the execution of following line of code:

```
var result = table.ReadAsync("$top=10", null, wrapResult: true).Result;
```

It would be great know if anybody had similar issue and were able resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

Calling .Result like the following will cause a deadlock

```
var result = table.ReadAsync("$top=10", null, wrapResult: true).Result;
```

I had the same issue with MobileServicesClient.InvokeApiAsync() call

Instead you should await like:-

```
async Task ReadTable()
{
        var result = await table.ReadAsync("$top=10", null, wrapResult: true); 

        // do something with result
}
```

Or in my case

```
async Task CallApi()
{
    var response = await App.client.InvokeApiAsync ("/api/call", System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get, null);

    // do something with response
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you're experimenting is normal since ReadAsync is an asynchronous method.  To "wait" for the call to complete, you need to use the await keyword.

var result = **await** table.ReadAsync("$top=10", null, wrapResult: true).Result;

You can read more about async support in Xamarin by reading this Xamarin documentation: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/async_support_overview/

Comment: "Await" keyword is not necessary here as I am not asynchronously waiting for results to come back. Just ReadAsync().Result should ideally be fine.

But, the actual problem I am facing is different. The control doesn't return right after the execution of ReadAsync call.